# linq query comparing Dates within a list

Tags: linq

I have a list object, lets call it "Parent". Within Parent a have several "Child" objects.  Within "Child", I have a DateTime property called StartDay.

I would like to run a linq query that will examine Parent and return the day of the week of StartDay if it is always the same day of the week.  If for example we have some StartDay's on wednesday and some on tuesday it will return "Variable".

Comment: As in 'the day of the week varies' and is not always on wednesday or whatever

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if all parents' children have the same `StartDay.DayOfWeek`:

```
bool allOnSameDay = Parent.All(p => {
     var firstChildDayOfWeek = p.Children.First().StartDay.DayOfWeek;
     return p.Children.All(c => c.StartDay.DayOfWekk == firstChildDayOfWeek);
})
```

Comment: Since OP asks for an actual day of the week (as a string, perhaps) maybe edit this answer.  Along the lines of `return p.Children.All().... ? firstChildDayOfWeek.ToString() : "Variable"`

Answer (score 0):

```
parents.Where(x => x.Children.Any())
  .Select(x => new { Parent = x, StartDays = x.Children.Select(y => y.StartDay).Distinct() })
  .Select(x => new { x.Parent, StartDay = x.StartDays.Count() == 1 ? x.StartDays.Single().ToString() : "Variable" });
```